# How to close a dialog box opened in jQuery and update appropriate divs after AJAX call

Tags: jquery

I have an application that uses jQuery to open a dialog box with a form. If that form is filled out successfully, I'd like to be able to close the dialog box in the success case of my jQuery call, and update some of the divs on the page.

Is there a common command or way to do that? I can't find it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(){
    if (yourFormValidationFunctionReturnsTrue){
        $('#yourDialog').dialog('close');
        $('#yourDiv').html('<p>Stuff</p>')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ...in the last line, if it was an existing div, with some id, how would the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

The way to close a dialog would be: `$('#dialogid').dialog("close");` and then one way of setting the contents of divs is `$('#divid).html(newhtmlvalue);`

Comment: thanks.  What if the new html is part of the header that depends on data in the session. How could I just "refresh" that part or instead make logged_in div show up? like hide one div and how another...how would I do that?

Comment: hiding is $('#divid').hide(); you really should look up some of these jQuery questions on the jQuery site. There are a ton of things which jQuery can do that you might not even know yet, and looking up functions is the fastest way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the docs:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

You just need to implement success (and preferably also error) handlers for ajax calls.